# Spring batch ApplicationContext

Tags: java, asynchronous, spring-batch, applicationcontext

I am using spring batch application in my project. Once i started the spring batch main method, at the end of main method , I am using to close the classpathxmlapplicationcontext.

1. Is it necessary to close to classpathxmlapplicationcontext?
2. One of major problem is, if i triggered any async calls in between within my batch application, then those async calls will be terminated when main method code reached to  classpathxmlapplicationcontext.close() ?
3. If i commented classpathxmlapplicationcontext.close() then , my program is running continuously without any termination even though all logic are completed.
4. How to resolve this? I need all my async calls will be executed before closing my classpathxmlapplicationcontext.
5. Consider all my async will take little bit excess time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes We have to close classpathxmlapplicationcontext.

Try the below code

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(...);
try {
    [...]
} finally {
    ctx.close();
}
```

Or, in Java 7 or after

```
try(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(...)) {
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply vignesh. Need one more clarification. if we are closing context then all my @Async calls get terminated or interrupted if it all running. Those async calls are initiate in middle of my job.

Comment: @Tachi Your welcome. Kindly make it answer is useful